# Debug console for GWT/GXT

Tags: gwt, debugging, gxt

I need to see component tree of the GWT application. DOM tree will be also acceptable. Unfortunatelly GWT hosted browser does not provide access for devToolbar.

The only way I found is to compile to javascript and then use regular browser. But compilation takes enormous ammount of time.

ExtJS has [Debug Console](http://extjs.com/deploy/ext-3.0-rc1.1/examples/debug/debug-console.html), but I was not able to find something similar for GXT.

Please suggest the way you debug visual GWT applications.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I was just wanting this today FireBug + GWT. If you are adventurous you could look into  builds of GWT 2.0 where Out Of Process Hosted Mode will be available letting you debug in FireFox or other browsers.  Design: Out of Process Hosted Mode

The source for GWT is here http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/

I personally haven't hit the pain threshold to build this yet because I keep hearing 2.0 is "close"

Comment: Current GWT trunk OOPHM works really well. Especially with Firefox. A +1 from me on this.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a debugger in the same mould as Firebug but the GWT Log console is really, really handy for finding out what's happening within the JavaScript.

See: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/

Answer (score 1):

Normally one would use the IDE debugger to step through GWT code. but if the problem is a CSS/styling issue (which from the sound of the question, it seems to be), then that might not really help.

i guess compiling it and using firebug is the only tried and true way for css issues.

Comment: With debugger I can see that I have added panel with content to the container panel, but nothing is changed on the screen. I tried to repaint(), recalculate() (both are from GXT), neither help.

Answer (score 0):

Why is compilation into (pretty) JavaScript taking so much time? I don't think it should. Perhaps you should disable compilation for irrelevant browsers (irrelevant for debugging purposes), thereby reducing compilation time significantly.

Comment: It takes 60 secs, I am using IDEA and most of the time it display "Loading inherited modules". I have GXT and two custom inherited modules.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to minimize compile time by reducing the permutations (different version for each browser) during development.

In your module.gwt.xml force an user agent, for example gecko1_8 (Firefox 2).

```
<!-- User Agent -->
<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8" />
```

If you're using i18n you can also limit the locales used during development.